# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to set up as has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in my rails application, between an Employee model and a NetworkDrive model.

In employee.rb I specified

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :network_drives</code>
```

and in network_drive.rb...

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :employee</code>
```

However, it seems to be generating model attributes like ":network_drife_ids" instead of ":network_drive_ids", which is giving me errors like

`uninitialized constant Employee::NetworkDrife`

which is accurate, considering the model is called NetworkDrive, not NetworkDrife.

Sorry if this is a repeat question, but I wasn't sure how to search for this problem. I tried several solutions provided by questions about HABTM relationships on here, but to no avail.

Update:  Here's the whole error, after trying to change it to as has_many :through relationship.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant EmployeeItRequest::EmployeeItRequestDrife
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:111:in `compute_type'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:216:in `association_primary_key'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:104:in `foreign_key_present?'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:165:in `find_target?'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:332:in `load_target'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:44:in `load_target'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:87:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Update: Result of NetworkDrive.tableize

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `tableize' for #<Class:0x0000000229fef8>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: please post the whole error msg.

Comment: What's the result of `NetworkDrive.tableize` in console?

Comment: both ends of the relationship should be plural - `HABTM :employees`.  Don't know if that'd do what you're seeing or not, but it'll definitely break somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a problem of HABTM, but one of rails' built-in inflection rules, which convert `drives` to the singular `drife` instead of `drive`.

In the console:

```
"drives".singularize  # => "drife"
```

You can override the default format by adding inflection rules:

**initializers/inflections.rb**

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.clear :inflection_drives
  inflect.irregular 'network_drive', 'network_drives'
end
```

Comment: The original code I posted was rails 2 format, just updated to rails 3.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! Do you mind me asking where I go about adding these rules? Nevermind...just saw, thanks!

Comment: initializers/inflections.rb is where inflection rules normally go.